# The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I have a table_Project with a CustomerID in it (linked to tbl_Customer). In tbl_Customer I have Customer_ID(as key) and some other info like Phone, Email etc.

To delete it from the Gridview I use this DeleteCommand:

```
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [tbl_Customer] WHERE [Customer_ID] = @Customer_ID"
```

But it gives me the following error:

`The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "Klant_Relatie". The conflict occurred in database "Database_1", table "dbo.tbl_Project", column 'CustomerID'.
The statement has been terminated.`

But with updating the CustomerInfo I do not get any error. I have seen different solutions for C# but I use .net

Any idea's?

Comment: YOU HAVE TO FIRST DELETE ALL ROWS PERTAINING TO table_Project WITH THE SAME CUSTOMER ID AS IT WILL BE HAVING FOREIGN KEY RELATION TO tbl_Customer

Comment: have u tried delete on cascade????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem has something to do with referential integrity. You cannot delete a record (*from table `tbl_Customer`*) which is currently being referenced by some records in a certain table (*table `table_Project` for example*). `UPDATE` is different from `DELETE` unless you are updating the key, in your case `CustomerID`. `UPDATE` modifies a record while `DELETE` removes the record.

Take a look at this example,

**tbl_Customer table**

```
CustomerID  CustomerName
1           Hello
2           World
```

**table_Project table**

```
CustomerID  ProjectName
1           Webscripting
1           Database Maintenance
```

You can always do anything you want on record `2` of table `tbl_customer` because there is no record that is referencing to it. But in record `1`, you can't delete it unless the two records from table `table_Project` are deleted. You can modify column `CustomerName` but not `CustomerID` is if still being referenced.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot delete the client if he is referenced by a project.. That's what the error means..

I don't understand your

> I have seen different solutions for C# but I use .net

But you have different solutions here:

1. Change the client referenced by all projects linked to old one (the one you want to delete)
2. Drop constraint (Not really good option)
3. Delete project before deleting the client (manually or by using cascade delete)

Answer (score 2):

Another thing you could do is in SQL server change the foreign key link so that on delete it cascades. This will cause the records to delete downward. So if you delete a record in table a, any record in table b that references that record will also get deleted.