# Delete specific values from column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I want to delete specific values/data from one column with the `WHERE` condition.

Table `CIVILITE`:

```
ID_CIVILITE CIV_LIBELLE
1           M.
2           Mme
3           Mlle
4           Aucun

DELETE FROM CIVILITE WHERE CIV_LIBELLE='Aucun';
```

Error:

> The DELETE statement is in conflict with the constraint REFERENCE
>   "FK_PERS_CIVILITE". The conflict occurred in database "DBDB",
>   "dbo.PERSONNE" table, column 'ID_CIVILITE'.

How can delete some value where there is a constraint ..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970893/the-delete-statement-conflicted-with-the-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you are getting this error is because you are trying to delete a row which is being referenced by another row hence resulting in the error. So either delete the reference row or remove the constraint temporarily. You need to first alter your table like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [DBDB].[dbo].[PERSONNE] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PERS_CIVILITE]
```

and then you can delete the record.

Make sure that once you delete the record you apply the constraint again.

```
ALTER TABLE [DBDB].[dbo].[PERSONNE] WITH CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PERS_CIVILITE]
```

Comment: The  good command is `ALTER TABLE PERSONNE CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_PERS_CIVILITE`

Answer (score 1):

Seems table CIVILITE column ID_CIVILITE is a primary key, first delete the similar rows in referenced table i.e foreign key table.

```
-- Run 1st
DELETE FROM [PERSONNE]
WHERE ID_CIVILITE IN
(SELECT CIVILITE WHERE CIV_LIBELLE='Aucun')
-- Run 2nd
DELETE CIVILITE WHERE CIV_LIBELLE='Aucun'
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you `DROP` the `constraint`, or -probably better- you update the data in Personnes so that no record has the value "Aucun".  You might set it no `Null` if it is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a table like `PERSON`, which has a foreign key constraint like:

```
create table person (
    -- various columns
    civilite_id int,
    foreign key component civilite_id references civilite(id_civilite)
);
```

and this table must have some rows that have civilite_id = 4.

You must either:

- remove the constraint
- delete the rows with this civilite
- update the rows to have a null civilite (if you can)
- update the rows to a different civilite